# How to solve a system of non linear equations

Tags: approximation, spline

I have the following system of non linear equations, and I want to solve it using fsolve but how do I do that?

```
function F = myfun(a0,a1,a2,b0,b1,b2,c0,c1,c2,x1,x2)
F = [a0-1;
    a0 + a1*x1 + a2*x1^2 - exp(-x1^2);
    b0 + b1*x1 + b2*x1^2 - exp(-x1^2);
    b0 + b1*x2 + b2*x2^2 - exp(-x2^2);
    c0 + c1*x2 + c2*x2^2 - exp(-x2^2);
    c0 + c1*2 + c2*4 - exp(-4);
    a1 + 2*a2*x1 - b1 - 2*b2*x1;
    b1 + 2*b2*x2 - c1 - 2*c2*x2;
    a0*(x1)+a1*(x1^2)/2+a2*(x1^3)/3+b0*(x2-x1)+b1*(x2^2-x1^2)/2+b2*(x2^3-x1^3)/3+c0*(2-x2)+c1*(4-x2^2)/2+c2*(8-x2^3)/3-0.8820813907624216799;
    a0*(x1^2)/2+a1*(x1^3)/3+a2*(x1^4)/4+b0*(x2^2-x1^2)/2+b1*(x2^3-x1^3)/3+b2*(x2^4-x1^4)/4+c0*(4-x2^2)/2+c1*(8-x2^3)/3+c2*(16-x2^4)/4-0.4908421805556329098;
    a0*(x1^3)/3+a1*(x1^4)/4+a2*(x1^5)/5+b0*(x2^3-x1^3)/3+b1*(x2^4-x1^4)/4+b2*(x2^5-x1^5)/5+c0*(8-x2^3)/3+c1*(16-x2^4)/4+c2*(32-x2^5)/5-0.422725056492476659]
end
```

Comment: What kind of approximation and how accurate does it have to be? What about $f(x)\approx 1-x^2$? Also why not use $\exp(-x^2)$ itself? Why do you need an approximation?

Comment: I'm approximating it for the sake of approximating it with least square sense via numerical methods, and seeing its accuracy compared to the actual function. I have a system of non linear equations, and I have to solve for their coefficients using fsolve, And from there I can approximate the function but I'm not sure how to go about that

Comment: If you have a system of equation to solve, show us what those equations are and maybe we can help. You forgot to mention that your code is in MATLAB. Have you used "fsolve" before?